# Converting Integer value into AnsiString in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, integer, ansistring

`IntToStr()` function returns string which is Unicode now. I want to convert to `AnsiString`.
Can I use `AnsiString(IntToStr(I))` safely?

Answer (score 7):

Sure. Or you can use `IntToAnsiString` (written by [Dr. Bob](http://www.bobswart.nl/Weblog/Blog.aspx?RootId=5:2984)):

```
function IntToAnsiStr(X: Integer; Width: Integer = 0): AnsiString;
begin
   Str(X: Width, Result);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can safely convert the `UnicodeString` returned by `IntToStr` to an `AnsiString`. The reason it's safe is that the string it returns will only contain the digit characters `'0'` through `'9'`, not any fancy Unicode digits, so the conversion to `AnsiString` will not lose any information.